# Relative rate of solvolysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I underestimated this question and just compared the carbocation stability of all the compounds (after removal of chloride via $S_N1$) and got the order D>C>B>A... but my answer is incorrect, what am I missing out?

Comment: Can't we bend the ring and bring that O closer, so as to have some intramolecular stabilization?

Comment: Is the answer A>B>D>C , if it is then I'll provide my reasoning . If it's not then  I'll wait for the question to get answered.

Comment: @AvatarShiny I don't know the correct order but C has the fastest solvolysis rate

Comment: @IvanNeretin why would we want to bring the O close that would make its -I more intense, making the carbocation further unstable (except if we bring the O at $\alpha$ wrt -Cl group...so it can be stabilized by +M)

Comment: Bringing O closer _does not_ make its -I more intense. -I spreads along sigma bonds, roughly speaking.

Comment: yh that's true...I meant bringing O closer would make -I more intense for the carbocation(as Inductive effects diminish with distance, right) until its at $\alpha$ position to the carbocation

Comment: -I does not care about distance. What it cares about is the number of bonds between O and (+).

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to say...more number of bonds =more distance(not always I know)

Comment: _double sigh_ @IvanNeretin This OP is very resistant to any hints. @ OP just read about neighbouring group participation.

Comment: @Mithoron OP? what does that mean?

Comment: It's you - original poster. BTW I have a feeling you should start you read thoroughly some good organic chem. textbook, a bit advanced one maybe. NGP (anchimeric assistance or whatever to call it) is significantly more tricky then inductive effect.

Comment: @Mithoron you have no idea how many books I've read about organic chemistry lol...I've read Jerry march, Paula bruice, peter sykes, solomons, Morrison boyd....but I just don't seem to remember...this question isn't a very tough one I know...I think

Comment: @Mithoron I guess  i'll be deleting this question and i'll find a way out on my own...now this just got on my self-respect

Comment: Well, I don't think you should delete, while "homeworky" a question about NGP should be valuable for the site IMO. You have put reasoning, but it's rather over your head. Even I can't tell outright what's the answer. You can answer yourself if you find out, though.

Comment: @Mithoron I got the answer right after you said you should read more books lol...now i'll answer my own question.

Comment: Can you tell the source of this question and the answer too(if it is provided)?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I got this question in my test

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image][image]

The rate of solvolysis is highest in (C) as a 6 membered ring is formed which is more stable than 4 & 5 membered rings.

And (B) more readily formed than (D) because the NGP ability of oxygen is more than that of an alkene(due to high charge density of oxygen).

So the correct order is C>B>D>A.

Comment: Well this question was easy and I have no idea why I couldn't possibly answer it earlier...thank you everyone for still paying attention

Comment: And here I thought to tell you to be careful with answering. This is not how NGP works; neighbouring groups stabilize cation by binding to it. Read your textbook again.